# Effective OO Design

Tags: c++, oop

I'm a newbie in OO design and there is one of SOLID principles is LISKOV Substitution Principle.

But in my design I've a classes named StartCommunicationMessage, ContinueCommunicationMessage, EndCommunicationMessage, AbortCommunicationMessage.

**StartCommunicationMessage** contains: *commID*, *qualityOfCommunication*, DestAddr, origAddr
**EndCommunicationMessage** contains: *commID*, *qualityOfCommunication*, *DestAddr*
**ContinueCommunicationMessage** contains: *commID*, *qualityOfCommunication*, *DestAddr*, *origAddr*
**AbortCommunicationMessage** contains: *commID*, *DestAddr*

So I can make make a parent for all of these message called **CommunicationMessage** that contains: *commID*, *DestAddr*

But *qualityOfCommunication* is not found in Abort, so it will be repeated as well as it getter and setter in all other classes which make a duplication.

Is there a way to reduce this duplication either by violating the above rule or anything else?

Comment: As is always the case with such OOP questions, it all depends on how clients will use the base class. If I have some code which has a `CommunicationMessage&`, how should it interact with that instance? Are clients aware of things like ID or quality? Should clients write and read those values directly? Good OOP design is first and foremost good interface design, and good interface design is all about "how will others use this?".

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Yes you got my point, yes clients will aware of these fields, also some of them are optional.

Comment: Clients should not be aware of fields but only of member functions. Fields (aka "member variables" in C++) should almost always be `private`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: They know about fields throw getters and setters not directly

Comment: That is *almost* like accessing the fields directly. There is a great answer on this topic by R. Martinho Fernandes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters (see "A public field is not worse than a getter/setter pair that does nothing except returning the field and assigning to it")

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is only to reduce duplication, it's not hard:

Another level of inheritance:

```
CommunicationMessage -> AbortCommunicationMessage, CommunicationMessageWithQuality  
CommunicationMessageWithQuality -> the other three classes
```

Or classes with multiple parents:

```
CommunicationMessage -> All 4 classes  
CommunicationMessage and Qualityclass -> Everything but AbortMessage
```

If that many classes really help for some message type,
or if they make everything more complicated, is a different thing...

Comment: Best thing would be to use composition and not inheritance.